# Paragraph Justify alignment not working

Tags: richedit

Using Visual Studio 2013 Community and Windows 7.

Left, right and centre align work fine, but PFA_JUSTIFY and PFA_FULL_INTERWORD do not.
They both align to the left. From my understanding Justify should insert spaces on lines so that the paragraph fills the available screen area, i.e. each line in the paragraph should start at the left-hand side and end at the right-hand side.

MSDN says PFA_JUSTIFY does not work and acts like left-align in richedit version 2. I read that 
PFA_FULL_INTERWORD is available in richedit version 3 (cannot remember where).

I checked richedit.h and found that PFA_JUSTIFY and PFA_FULL_INTERWORD are both defined as constant value 4. Is that a mistake or are they synonyms?

I need Justify for some applications.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I used this, but RichEdit 3 will do full justification with PFA_FULL_INTERWORD, but only if "advanced typography options" have been turned on with another call: assuming a C-like language, make sure you call

```
SendMessage(hRichEditWnd,EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS,
    TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY,TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY);
```

when initializing the RichEdit control. See the MSDN article on [EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for more information.

Comment: Thank you. You'd think Microsoft would have this info in their MSDN page for `PFA_FULL_INTERWORD` style for `PARAFORMAT2` struct description....